# Update values to firebase

Tags: html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Values are not getting updated in the Firebase Realtime Database. I am new to web development but I knew a little html. Can you please check what the problem here. 
I left Firebase Config blank intentionally for this question.
I tried using most of the code given in Firebase documentation.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<title>"Web App"</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="mainDiv" align="left">
  <h1 align="left">"Firebase web page"</h1>
  <textarea id="Command" placeholder="ON/OFF" stClyle="text align:left; overflow:auto; border:6px outset #000000;"></textarea>
  <button id="Submit" onclick="submitclick()">Click Me!</button>
</div>

<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-web-app -->

<script>
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {

apiKey: "___________________________",
authDomain: "_________.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://___________.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "________",
storageBucket: "_________.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "________",
appId: "_____________"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var mainTxt= document.getElementById("Command"); 
var submitbtn = document.getElementById("Submit");
function submitclick()
{

var com = mainTxt.value;
firebase.database().ref().child("username").set(com);
}
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have typo in database in `firebase.dtabase().ref().child(...).set(..)`. Should be `firebase.database().ref().child(....).set(...)`

Comment: Yeah.. Sorry for that. I added that line i copied the code here. But that does not solve the problem its still not working.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: i have 1 child in main: "username"... also i have already set up the web app.

Comment: in rules both read and write are true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation on how to add Firebase to your Web/JavaScript project: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

By doing

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>`

you are adding the Firebase **core** library, but **this is not sufficient**. You have to add the library(ies) for the service(s) you are going to use, in your case the Realtime Database.

Therefore you need to do

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

---

Note the following line

```
<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
```

in your own code: it indicates exactly what is described above.

Answer (score 1):

First of all to use firebase you have to include

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.1.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

Still it won't work because this is not how you write to firebase. You write as key value pairs. Try

```
firebase.database().collection("userNames").add({name : "user_name"});
```

or if you trying to update a document

```
firebase.database().ref().child("userName").set({name : "user_name"});
```

Here is the official documentation : [Add and Manage Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

As on the topic calling **.set()** or **.add()** may not always write data  you have to check by using **then()** and **catch()**.

So a complete example of updating a document value in firebase will be :

```
// Add a new document in collection "cities"
db.collection("users").doc("userName").set({
    name: "USER_NAME"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```